# What is the NavigationUI class for?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I am starting to use NavController and I have seen that NavigationUI can make things easier, I have read the documentation, but it is not very clear to me.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI

If someone could explain to me its main uses or what it is useful for, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NavigationUI` is a `static`.

It includes some auxiliary functions.

**onNavDestinationSelected**

Attempt to navigate to the `[NavDestination]` associated with the given `MenuItem`

**navigateUp**

Handles the Up button by delegating its behavior to the given `NavController`.

**setupActionBarWithNavController**

Sets up the `ActionBar`

**setupWithNavController**

Sets up a `[Toolbar]` for use with a `[NavController]`

...

In short, it will connect to NavController. There are methods to make navigation processes easier.

[Source](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/navigation/navigation-ui/2.4.0-alpha01-source/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.kt.html)